# 8-bit quasi-bidirectional I/O port

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, port, bidirectional

The schematic attached is from a very old device. It's using the microcontroller SAB 80535. According to the datasheet P5.7-P5.0 is an 8-bit quasi-bidirectional I/O port. There's a keyboard, a LCD and some outputs connected in parallel to this port. I would like to design an external/remote board to control this port so I can use the information coming in/out the port somewhere else. I was looking at this chip [PCF8574](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/pcf8574) which looks like I could connect it to the parallel port and send/receive information via I2C using another microcontroller. Am I using this chip right? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: the PCF8574 has only 8 data pins ... how will you know when to latch the data coming out of the SAB80535?

Comment: I think I should find out the function of ports P1, P3, P4 and add another PCF8574

Comment: _"I would like to design an external/remote board to **control** this port"_ - so you want to disable the MCU and control the pereipherals (LCD, keyboard etc.) with via I2C to PCF8574s?

Comment: look at the 2x20 vf display I/O pins ... what do you see?

Comment: @jsotola 2x20 display is actually not connected, it's optional. I could connect my device to those pins. But I can see read/write/enable pins.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The idea in general is to control this port (get output data to LCD, input data from keyboard). The PCF8574 is an option I'm considering. Maybe there are better ways.

Comment: good, the data pins would have valid data output when enable pin is low and the write pin is low ... the data may actually be valid on rising, or falling edge of the write pin ... so, watch the states of the enable and write pins ... then read the data bits .... it is unclear where the LCD connects, but it can probably be read the same way

Comment: I have been playing mcp23x08/17 and pcf8574. They are all good, depending on your app, skills, and schedule.